# Proving that the composition of a harmonic function and a Cauchy-Riemann mapping is harmonic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multivalued-functions

> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open subset of the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and
>   let the mapping $F : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be
>    represented by $F(x, y) = (u(x, y), v(x, y))$ for $(x, y)$ in
>    $\mathcal{O}$. Then, we say the mapping $F : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is called a *Cauchy-Riemann mapping* provided that
>    each of the functions $u : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $v
>  : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has continuous second-order
>    partial derivatives and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x, y) =
>  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x, y) \hspace{1em} \text{ and }
>  \hspace{1em} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial
>  v}{\partial x}(x, y)$$
>
> for all $(x, y)$ in $\mathcal{O}$.

Prove that if $w : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic and the mapping $F : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a Cauchy-Riemann mapping, then the function $w \circ F : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also harmonic.

---

So I know that a function is harmonic provided that the sum of its second derivatives equals $0$. This means we have $\nabla^2 w = 0$.

Also, we can write $F(x, y) = (u(x, y), v(x,y))$. I don't really know how to prove this fact. We have the relations above in the definition of a Cauchy-Riemann mapping, but I'm not so sure about where to use them.

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Replace $\Bbb{R}^2$ by $\Bbb{C}$. Cauchy-Riemann means $\partial_y F = i \partial_x F $ and harmonic means $\partial_y^2 w=-\partial_x^2 w$.


$\partial_{y^2} (w \circ F) =\partial_{y} ( (\partial_yF) ((\partial_y w) \circ F))=(\partial_y^2 F) ((\partial_y w) \circ F)+(\partial_y F)^2 ((\partial_y^2 w) \circ F)$